# Search database and project results to datagridview

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, vb.net-2010

I have an sql database with about 100 different variables. What I basically want is to be able to search the database based on some of the variables either as one by one or as a multiple search.
For this purpose I have created a search form in VS 2010 with the desired number of comboboxes (each combobox represents one variable and takes distinct values from the database).
Based on which variables the user chose i want the results to be shown on a datagridview table.

The code for some reason is wrong and I can't figure it out. The problem is located da.Fill(datatable1) with an unexpected error.
Is there any alternatives and provide some guidelines to complete the idea?

```vb
Private Sub display_datagrid()
    con2.ConnectionString = "Server= DESKTOP-KQG48T5\SQL2021; Database = Fotilas2021; Integrated Security = True;"
    con2.Open()

    
    Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("select Name,IdentityNumber,FatherSurname,LocalCelebDay,BirthNomos,NumofChilds,MilitaryService,CurrentCountry,CurrentCity,CellNumber,DateAdd,Occupation,OccupPosition,ElectWeight,ElectContact,ElectCategory,ElectCollege,DeleteGroup,ElectPeriphery,Sex,FatherName,MotherName,Birthday,FamilyStatus,BirthDimos,Adreess,CurrentNomos,Landline,OccupSpeciality,ElectImportance,ElectMechanism,ElectPeriphery,ElectDimotikiEnotita,ElectNumber,EduLanguages,SuggestSurname,SuggestPhone,ElectDimos,EduUniversity,Surname,FatherSurname,WifeName,NameDay,BirthCountry,BirthCity,HealthStatus,Postcode,CurrentDimos,HomeLine,Fax,OccupStatus,OccupFirm,ElectType,ElectCategory,ElectDiamerisma,EduLevel,EduPC,ElectEterodimotis,EduQualifications from Fotilas2021 where Name like '%" + ComboBox2.Text + "%', IdentityNumber like '%" + ComboBox3.Text + "%', FatherSurname like '%" + ComboBox4.Text + "%', LocalCelebDay like '%" + ComboBox5.Text + "%', BirthNomos like '%" + ComboBox6.Text + "%', NumofChilds like '%" + ComboBox7.Text + "%', MilitaryService like '%" + ComboBox8.Text + "%' CurrentCountry like '%" + ComboBox9.Text + "%', CurrentCity like '%" + ComboBox10.Text + "%', CellNumber like '%" + ComboBox11.Text + "%', DateAdd like '%" + ComboBox13.Text + "%', Occupation like '%" + ComboBox14.Text + "%', OccupPosition like '%" + ComboBox15.Text + "%', ElectWeight like '%" + ComboBox16.Text + "%', ElectContact like '%" + ComboBox17.Text + "%', ElectCategory like '%" + ComboBox19.Text + "%', ElectCollege like '%" + ComboBox20.Text + "%', DeleteGroup like '%" + ComboBox21.Text + "%', ElectPeriphery like '%" + ComboBox22.Text + "%', Sex like '%" + ComboBox30.Text + "%', FatherName like '%" + ComboBox31.Text + "%', MotherName like '%" + ComboBox32.Text + "%', Birthday like '%" + ComboBox33.Text + "%', FamilyStatus like '%" + ComboBox34.Text + "%', BirthDimos like '%" + ComboBox35.Text + "%', Adreess like '%" + ComboBox37.Text + "%', CurrentNomos like '%" + ComboBox38.Text + "%', Landline like '%" + ComboBox39.Text + "%', OccupSpeciality like '%" + ComboBox43.Text + "%', ElectImportance like '%" + ComboBox45.Text + "%', ElectMechanism like '%" + ComboBox50.Text + "%', ElectPeriphery like '%" + ComboBox51.Text + "%', ElectDimotikiEnotita like '%" + ComboBox52.Text + "%', ElectNumber like '%" + ComboBox53.Text + "%', EduLanguages like '%" + ComboBox56.Text + "%', SuggestSurname like '%" + ComboBox57.Text + "%', SuggestPhone like '%" + ComboBox29.Text + "%', ElectDimos like '%" + ComboBox23.Text + "%', EduUniversity like '%" + ComboBox27.Text + "%', Surname like '%" + ComboBox59.Text + "%', FatherSurname like '%" + ComboBox60.Text + "%', WifeName like '%" + ComboBox61.Text + "%', NameDay like '%" + ComboBox62.Text + "%', BirthCountry like '%" + ComboBox63.Text + "%', BirthCity like '%" + ComboBox64.Text + "%', HealthStatus like '%" + ComboBox65.Text + "%', Postcode like '%" + ComboBox66.Text + "%', CurrentDimos like '%" + ComboBox67.Text + "%', HomeLine like '%" + ComboBox68.Text + "%', Fax like '%" + ComboBox69.Text + "%', OccupStatus like '%" + ComboBox71.Text + "%', OccupFirm like '%" + ComboBox72.Text + "%', ElectType like '%" + ComboBox74.Text + "%', ElectCategory like '%" + ComboBox76.Text + "%', ElectDiamerisma like '%" + ComboBox81.Text + "%', EduLevel like '%" + ComboBox84.Text + "%', EduPC like '%" + ComboBox85.Text + "%', ElectEterodimotis like '%" + ComboBox25.Text + "%', EduQualifications like '%" + ComboBox28.Text + "%'", con1)

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim datatable1 As New DataTable

    da.SelectCommand = command
    datatable1.Clear()
    da.Fill(datatable1)
    DtGrid_Search.DataSource = datatable1
    con2.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the datatype of IdentityNumber? Is this the primary key of the table?

Comment: I believe you say you have used distinct values form the database to fill the combo boxes so why all the Like %...%? I assume some of the fields are number types and date types? How is one number "Like" another? How is one date "Like" another? It seems all of that should be = (equals)

Comment: Is the user able to select values from none, some, all combo boxes? What values are you sending if the user makes no selection from the combo?

Comment: You have some duplicate fields in your Select list.

Comment: The conditions in the Where clause need to be separated by AND or OR.

Comment: ID is an Integer. Basically each combobox is a different variable. For example one combobox takes values of the countries, one combobox of the districts and one of the cities. So why instead of LIKE use equal;

Comment: The user can select values from all comboboxes. I haven't figured the null command though. Duplicate fields i can't find. I have search the code 10 times .Where should I put the AND or OR in the code.

Comment: Using `like` with wildcards means that a user searching for `'day'` will match `'Monday'`, `'Dayton'`, `'Doomsdayers', ... as Mary suggested. Is that what they expect having picked a value from a list? What do they expect if they search by two columns, e.g. both _must_ match (AND) or either matches (OR)? See [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). SQL databases have _tables_ which consist of _rows_ and _columns_. Where are the _variables_ you are searching?

Comment: ElectCategory,
ElectPeriphery,
FatherSurname are the 3 fields in the select list that are duplicated. You put the AND or OR in the between the Where conditions. See the answer by jmcilhinney for how to handle no selection in a combo box.

Answer (score 2):

You should use parameters for a start, and you should construct your SQL so that each parameter is effectively optional, e.g.

```vb
Dim sql = <sql>
              SELECT *
              FROM SomeTable
              WHERE (@Column1 IS NULL OR Column1 = @Column1)
              AND (@Column2 IS NULL OR Column2 = @Column2)
              AND (@Column3 IS NULL OR Column3 = @Column3)
          </sql>
```

There are a number of things to note here.

Firstly, this code uses an XML literal. Before multiline `String` literals were introduced in (I think) 2015, that is the best way to write long inline SQL, because it allows you to break it over multiple lines without clutter making it hard to read.

Secondly, the SQL code uses parameters. If you think of the SQL code as being like a VB method, each of the things prefixed with `@` is basically a method parameter. When you execute the SQL code, you provide a value for each of those parameters, just like when you call a VB method. Parameters make your code easier to read, not subject to formatting issues and, most importantly, not subject to SQL injection attacks. You can do some research to find out more if you want.

Finally, the way each parameter is used makes them effectively optional by allowing you to set a parameter to `NULL` to make it effectively ignored. For example, if you set the `@Column1` to `NULL` then the first criterion in the `WHERE` clause will be true for every record, so it's like not having that criterion at all. If, on the other hand, you set `@Columnn1` to a value then the first criterion will only be true for records that contain that value in `Column1`. The same goes for each of the other parameters, so you can have as many "optional" parameters as you like.

The way to make use of this in your VB code would be as follows:

```vb
Dim table As New DataTable

Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, "connection string here")
    With adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters
        .Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ComboBox1.Text
        .Add("@Column2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ComboBox2.Text
        .Add("@Column3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ComboBox3.Text
    End With

    adapter.Fill(table)
End Using

BindingSource1.DataSource = table
DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
```

Obviously the details may vary but the principle is fixed: create a data adapter with the SQL code, add the appropriate parameter to the `SelectCommand` and then call `Fill` to populate your `DataTable`. You can then do whatever you want with that, e.g. bind it to a `DataGridView` via a `BindingSource`. When you add a parameter, just specify the same name as you used in the SQL code and the appropriate database data type, then set the `Value` to the appropriate value from your app, casting or converting the data as appropriate.

For example, if you are using a parameter to compare to a column that is `varchar(50)` in the database then you specify `SqlDbType.VarChar` and `50` when adding the parameter and you set the `Value` using a `String`. If your database column is type `int` then you specify `SqlDbType.Int` and no size, then set the `Value` using an `Integer`.

If you want ignore a paramater then, as I said, you needs to set it to `NULL` in the SQL. That might look like this in the VB code:

```vb
.Add("@Column1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = If(ComboBox1.SelectedItem Is Nothing, CObj(DBNull.Value), ComboBox1.Text)
.Add("@Column2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = If(ComboBox2.SelectedItem Is Nothing, CObj(DBNull.Value), ComboBox2.Text)
.Add("@Column3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = If(ComboBox3.SelectedItem Is Nothing, CObj(DBNull.Value), ComboBox3.Text)
```

In each case, the code first checks whether the user has selected an item in the appropriate `ComboBox` and, if not, the parameter's `Value` is set to `DBNull.Value`, which is the ADO.NET representation of a database `NULL`. If an item is selected, the selected value is used. You can modify the details of the code as required but, again, the principle is constant.

Note that the `CObj` is required because the `If` operator used here requires both possible return values to be the same type or one assignable to the other. `DBNull` and `String` are not the same type and neither inherits the other so you cannot use those two types. By casting one to type `Object` using `CObj`, you enable the other value to be any type, because every other type inherits `Object`.